# Detecting trends in a data stream in real-time

Tags: time-series, trend, online-algorithms

I'm trying to detect trending topics on Twitter in real-time. What I'm doing is every time I get a tweet I assign the tweet to the cluster that talks about the same topic as the tweet. Regardless of the clustering algorithm I'm using or how I'm assigning tweets to topics, I'm unable to find how to detect a trending topic.

My understanding or definition of the trending cluster/topic is that it's one that's getting assigned tweets more than the other clusters during a certain period of time. Or the frequency of updating the cluster size is more than the other clusters.

How to convert that definition into actual code or a mathematical model is what I'm unable to solve.

Comment: The portion of this question that asks for code is off-topic, but I think that we can leave this open with the understanding that an answer merely needs to describe a mathematical model for "online" clustering of some sort.